# Simple for loop not working

Tags: php, syntax, loops, for-loop, break

I've just started learning programming. I'm studying for loops but
this program does not work as expected. I want to break the loop when
`$a` is equal to `3` so that I get the output `1 2` but I get `3` as output :(

```
for($a=0;$a<10;++$a)
{
       if($a==3)
               break
       print"$a ";
}
```

Please help.

Comment: <religious>This is a good example to support the argument for always using curly braces. With them, you'd get a syntax error.</religious>

Comment: @bmb: + for the braces. I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 41):

**Missing semi-colon** after `break`

---

It's rather interesting to know why your program behaves the way it does.

The general syntax of `break` in PHP is:

```
break Expression;
```

The expression is optional, but if present its value tells how many nested
enclosing structures are to be broken out of.

`break 0;` and `break 1;` are same as `break;`

Your code is equivalent to

```
if($a==3)
       break print"$a ";
```

Now the [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) function in PHP always return `1`. Hence it is equivalent to

```
if($a==3)
       break 1;
```

so when `$a` is `3` you print its value and break.

It's advisable to use braces to enclose the body of a conditional or a loop even if the body has a single statement. In this case enclosing the `if` body in braces:

```
if($a==3) {
  break
}
print"$a ";
```

would have given a syntax error: PHP expects a `;` but finds a `}`

All of the above applies to the PHP `continue` as well. So the program

```
for($a=0;$a<10;++$a)
{
       if($a==3)
               continue
       print"$a ";
}
```

also prints `3` for a similar reason.

Comment: What the execution goose chase!

Comment: I actually didn't know that. +1

Answer (score 19):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of break. ;)

And even with the semicolon it will not work as you'd expect it to since it will count from `0` to `2`. You have to write it like this to get only `1 2`.

```
<?php
for($a=1;$a<10;++$a)
{
   if($a==3)
           break;
   print"$a ";
}
?>
```

Note $a is now one in the for loop initialization.

**EDIT:** Another thing I've noticed which you should be aware of. In your for loop control you have a pre-increment (`++$a`). That basically means that PHP increments the value of `$a` and then returns `$a`. Another option is the post-increment (`$a++`) where `$a` gets returned and then gets incremented by one.

In your case both ways will get you the correct output tho.

This sometimes is pretty important. Just keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4):

As codaddict said, you are missing the semi-colon after break.

Your code should look like:

```
for($a=0;$a<10;++$a)
{
       if($a==3)
           break;
       echo $a, ' ';
}
```

Comment: @Downvoters what was the problem with it ...

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the OP's problem is he *does not* get a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

```
for($a=0;$a<10;++$a)
{
       if($a==3) break;
       print $a;
}
```

@Downvoters: What's wrong aside from me being laconic?

Comment: not the down voter, but that else is redundant

Answer (score 0):

```
for($a=0;$a<10;$a++) {
   if($a==3) { exit; }
   else { echo $a; }
}
```

Comment: Using `exit` is probably not the correct idea - sticking with `break` would have been better.

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` in place of `print`.